# Tint UIBarButtonItems in inputAssistantItem on iPad

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a couple of `UIBarButtonItems` used to apply formatting to text in a `UITextView`. On iPhone, these buttons are added to a `UIToolbar` that's set as the `inputAcessoryView` for the textview. On iPad, the buttons are added to the textview's `inputAssistantItem` toolbar instead.

The states of the buttons are toggled on or off by changing the tintColor of the UIBarButtonItems (i.e. when the currently selected NSRange should be bold the tintColor of the bold button is changed to indicate that it is active).

This works great when the UIBarButtonItems are added to a UIToolbar on iPhone, but I can't get this to work for the inputAssistantItem on iPad. When I change the tintColor of a button, nothing changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested, I managed to fix this by adding a UIButton to to each UIBarButtonItem and then changing the tintColor of the button instead of the UIBarButtonItem.